# sqlalchemy engine.result.RowProxy to int in function with snowflake

Tags: python, mysql, function, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have searched the few questions with answers on SO with no luck.

[like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958219/how-to-convert-sqlalchemy-row-object-to-a-python-dict), [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297359/how-to-change-resultproxy-into-a-string), [or this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35774307/how-to-get-one-record-with-sqlalchemy), [and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093095/sqlalchemy-print-results-instead-of-objects)

I have a basic function that needs to read a log table, pull the max `batch_id`, and then create an object that is `batch_id +1` and stored as a number/int.

it neither creates the objects, nor can I turn the sql results into anything readable other than a RowProxy or NoneType.

```
def sf_get_batchid():
engine = create_engine(
'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/{database}/{schema}?warehouse=wh'.format(
    database='dev_db',
    schema='a_schema',
    user='user',
    password='password',
    account='account'
    )
)
connection = engine.connect()
print('Connected to DB: dev_db')
batchid_sql = "SELECT MAX(batch_id) FROM DEV_DB.A_SCHEMA.SN_DISTRIBUTION_LOG;" 
try:
    # execute sql
    result = connection.execute(batchid_sql)
    batch_id = result.fetchall()
    # return int(batch_id[0][0]) + 1
    new_batch_id = batch_id[0] +1
except Exception as e:
    print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
    sys.exit(1)
```

ultimately I want to just run this function with no args, and get two usable items

```
batch_id = the current max number
new_batch_id = that new number +1
```

thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=text#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text) and [`scalar()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=scalar#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult.scalar).  Also I'm not sure what `MAX` returns when the table is empty.  You might have to check for `None` or use `coalesce`.

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

batchid_sql = text("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(batch_id), 0) FROM DEV_DB.A_SCHEMA.SN_DISTRIBUTION_LOG")
try:
    # execute sql
    result = connection.execute(batchid_sql)
    batch_id = result.scalar()
    # return int(batch_id) + 1
    new_batch_id = batch_id + 1
except Exception as e:
    print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Also I don't think you can reliably get the "next id" this way if there are other writers to the same table unless you use locking.

Comment: Thank you!  this is helpful.  the table was seeded with a record and batch_id of 0.  since it's a table that only i write to, max and then max +1 has worked for me.  you are correct though, that it may be troublesome with many people writing to it.